# An exception was raised while creating "UserTable"; no instance returned

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new to zend framework2.

I got the error.
`An exception was raised while creating "UserTable"; no instance returned`.

Please look my code.

**Login\Model\UserTable.php**

```
protected $tableGateway;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}

public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

**Login\Module.php**

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'UserTable'          => function($serviceManager) {
                $tableGateway       = $serviceManager->get('UserTableGateway');
                return new UserTable($tableGateway);
            },
            'UserTableGateway' => function ($serviceManager) {
                $dbAdapter          = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype   = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(NULL);
                return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, NULL, $resultSetPrototype);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

**Login\src\Login\Controller\LoginController.php**

```
public function getAction()
{
    $serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $userTable = $serviceManager->get('UserTable');
    $user = $userTable->fetchAll();
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home', ['data' => $user]);
}
```

**local.php**

```
 return array(
  'db' => array(
    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=album; host=localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
  ),
  'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
        => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
  )
);
```

when I just redirect to home in `getAction()` in controller, it working fine.

I couldn't get solution for this.

can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE: please comment, if you need more details.**

Comment: Can you indicate where you're getting this error? What have you tried to resolve the issue and what did you bump into? Have you debugged the code using Xdebug? - As a side question, if you're new to Zend Framework, why are you starting with Zend Framework 2 instead of Zend Framework 3 (released in 2016) ? Asking because using the ServiceManager in Controllers is no longer allowed/possible in ZF3, so you'll be better off starting with ZF3 straight away and learning the current methods instead of the outdated/deprecated ones.

Comment: You forgot the `driver` key in the `db` config. Simply add `'driver' => 'Pdo'` and it should work.

Comment: About the ZF2 / ZF3, I totally agree with rkeet. You should avoind ZF2 and go directly with ZF3 ;)

Comment: actually, this code are given by client, and I have no time to upgrade it to zf3.